# {exp:assets:folders} not working with parent_folder parameter set

Tags: assets

EE version: 2.5.2 
Assets version: 2.1.2

I'm using the {exp:assets:folders} tag with the parent_folder parameter set and it's not working when that parameter is set.

This is an MSM site and I'm working on the 2nd site. I can see everything just fine within the control panel.

I've setup a dedicated page to test this out so that there aren't conflicts with other add-ons.  Here's my code:

```
<ul>
{exp:assets:folders parent_folder="{filedir_7}human-resources"}
    <li>
        <a href="{path=assets/view/{folder_id}}">{folder_name}</a>
        {if total_subfolders}
            <ul>
                {subfolders}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    </li>
{/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

This code does work:

```
<ul>
{exp:assets:folders}
    <li>
        <a href="{path=assets/view/{folder_id}}">{folder_name}</a>
        {if total_subfolders}
            <ul>
                {subfolders}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    </li>
{/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

What's strange is that using the parent_folder parameter worked at one time. I've looked back at my check-ins and don't see anything that would conflict with the Assets code.

I tried some debugging by looking at the _get_folder_id_by_tagpath function in mod.assets.php. I noticed that $tagpath is passed in as `http://intranet.compassoncology.com/uploads/human-resources` instead of `{filedir_7}human-resources`. The code appears to be expecting the latter. Is there something that could have happened to cause `{filedir_7}` to be replaced?

Thanks for any help or direction!

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this, so I've submitted it as a bug.  We'll update here with progress.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Lisa!  I think I may have also found a bug related to a feature added in 2.1.1, "Added the file_id parameter to the {exp:assets:files} tag". Should I start a new question related to that?

Comment: Mark - sure; or if you think you have a bug, go ahead and email directly to support@pixelandtonic.com.

Comment: ...any progress on this? I might be having the same issue with Assets 2.1.3 and EE 2.6.1.

Comment: Lisa? Any updates? IMO it's pretty serious when the example provided in the docs doesn't work... ;)

Comment: Hey, uhh, Sandwich :) I can't reproduce this on the latest Assets/EE. Are you still having issues? If so, shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com!

Comment: I am with Assets 2.2.1 and EE 2.7.1. I'll update to EE 2.7.2 and let you know...

Comment: Yup, still nothing displaying when trying to use the parent_folder parameter. Emailing now.

Comment: I went to update Assets today and am sad to see that this is still a problem. For what it's worth, I was able to hack Assets to make it work.  In mod.assets.php I changed line 249 from `$pattern = '/\{(filedir|source)_([0-9]+)\}([a-z0-9_\- \/]+)?/i';` to `$pattern = '/\[(filedir|source)_([0-9]+)\]([a-z0-9_\- \/]+)?/i';` and then used [filedir_X] instead of {filedir_X} in my template.